The window terminated unexpectedly (reason: 'crashed', code: '-1073741818')
screenshot of an error message from Visual Studio Code crashing

The window terminated unexpectedly (reason: 'crashed', code: '-1073741818')

This is the error message I've been getting in my VS Code since I've reset my computer a few times. This has happened since the first reset.
I haven't tried anything yet.
